# phonegap app exit not stopping the sound

Tags: android, cordova

This is something new I am experiencing.

```
 navigator.app.exitApp();
```

generally quits the app and stops all the activities.

But now it does quits the app but the background sound is still running. More like the app is not quitting rather it is being minimized.

Any idea? I am using phonegap 3.5. Platform android.